# Disable "Run last successful build" in Visual Studio Code (!)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

If a C# compile/build fails, I usually got a prompt whether to run the last successful build.

Somehow this dialog got turned off permanently. Now, if there is a compile error, VSC will automatically run the last successful build without a query, which is usually pretty useless and annoying.

How can I
(a) get back the query, and then, if possible,
(b) remove it, but in a way the last successful build is *not* executed?

Note: there is a documented procedure for Visual Studio, but I need the procedure for Visual Studio Code (latest version 1.61.0).

Thanx, Armin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saved in your [user settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Called:

```
"debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors"
```

The [options are](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4564730bd63ac6afd0e54495c14e231758bf68d1/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/common/debug.ts#L548):

- prompt (the default)
- debugAnyway (your setting)
- showErrors (what you seem to be looking for)
- abort (neither of the above)

It's in the UI as well, under "Features --> Debug --> On Task Errors":

[image: VS Code Debug configuration]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!